# Override and use front controller features in a prestashop module [1.6.x.x]

Tags: module, controller, extends, prestashop-1.6

I would like to edit and add features to the prestashop Store Locator page. 
Prestashop's documentation isn't really clear, and i would like to know if it's possible to implement a Controller in a custom module. 
I would like to create a module which is able to extends StoreFrontController and it's features without starting from scratch.
Is it possible ? Have you some documentation for me ?

A beginner, 
Best.

Comment: Sorry, my prestashop version is 1.6.1.5.

Comment: what kind of features would you like to add?

Comment: If you want to add more informations the process will be different than if you want to alter datas.

Comment: I would like to add two features: 

* The first and most important, get all the store information to create a dedicated page to each store. 
Ex: You find the nearest shop and can click on the name to be redirected to a cms page.  
                                                                             
* Second feature, assign one or more categories to a shop. 
Example : to search what is the nearest shop who sell category's products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have many requirements, you will have to go with an override of class `StoresController.php`.

Your module folder should look like this:

```
/mymodule
    /mymodule.php
    /config.xml
    /override
         /controllers
              /front
                   StoresController.php
    /views
         /templates
              /front
                   stores.tpl
```

In `StoresController.php` you will have to override `initContent()`:

```php
<?php

class StoresController extends StoresControllerCore
{

    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        // here add any smarty variables you want

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodule/views/templates/front/stores.tpl');
    }
}
```

Now you can add as many variables as you want in this controller and customized its template in your own module.

---

We you create an override in a module, it will be only parsed once at installation. If your module is already installed you will have to uninstall it and install it again. Then your override file will be copied to the root `/override` folder.

Any change made in your module override will not be reflected to the root override folder. So you will have to uninstall and install your module each time you want to make a change.

So I advise you to make all your changes directly in the root override folder, and when you're done copy this file back into your module folder. And if you don't want to uninstall your module and install it again to declare this file, you can put it directly in the root override folder and delete the file `/cache/class_index.php` so that Prestashop knows that an overrides has been added.

If you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your advises. It's really understadable. 

I have just another question, i am not familiar with prestashop so i want to understand. 

If i override this controller in my module, will it work normally ? i mean, only my changes will modify the controller behaviour, 
the rest will work as if I had changed nothing ?!

Comment: What do you mean by normally? Your override extends the Core StoresControllerCore. When Prestashop will load StoresController it will first look for an override and find yours. Then it will process it like any Controller class.

Comment: "i mean, only my changes will modify the controller behaviour, the rest will work as if I had changed nothing ?!" that's it. You can alter the controller the way you want in your override, but any method you didn't changed will run normally.

Comment: In my example I only declared a new template file. So instead of loading the default "stores.tpl" in your theme folder, it will now load the stores.tpl in your module folder. So you need to copy the default stores.tpl and modify it in your module. Later if you want to share this module with an other store, they will be able to alter your template file in `/themes/thetheme/modules/your_module/stores.tpl`. The default `/themes/thetheme/stores.tpl` will never be used again.

Comment: If you have any other questions feel free to post it in a new Question tagged Prestashop and I'll be pleased to help you again.

Comment: Perfect, you answer to me in a great way ! 
Really helpful ! 

And now begin the fight between me and prestashop, héhé. 

Thank you Florian.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by overriding front controller like

```
`"/modules/mymodule/override/controllers/front/StoresController.php" and in this fine add class "class StoresControllerCore extends FrontController {
public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
//here do whatever you like
}
}"
```

though you must know coding to proceed further.

Comment: Thank you ! 

Florian gave me a solution, and it works great !